# How to crop zero edges of a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, crop

I have this ugly, un-pythonic beast:

```
def crop(dat, clp=True):
    '''Crops zero-edges of an array and (optionally) clips it to [0,1].

    Example:
    >>> crop( np.array(
    ...       [[0,0,0,0,0,0],
    ...        [0,0,0,0,0,0],
    ...        [0,1,0,2,9,0],
    ...        [0,0,0,0,0,0],
    ...        [0,7,4,1,0,0],
    ...        [0,0,0,0,0,0]]
    ...     ))
    array([[1, 0, 1, 1],
           [0, 0, 0, 0],
           [1, 1, 1, 0]])
    '''
    if clp: np.clip( dat, 0, 1, out=dat )
    while np.all( dat[0,:]==0 ):
        dat = dat[1:,:]
    while np.all( dat[:,0]==0 ):
        dat = dat[:,1:]
    while np.all( dat[-1,:]==0 ):
        dat = dat[:-1,:]
    while np.all( dat[:,-1]==0 ):
        dat = dat[:,:-1]
    return dat
    # Below gets rid of zero-lines/columns in the middle
    #+so not usable.
    #dat = dat[~np.all(dat==0, axis=1)]      
    #dat = dat[:, ~np.all(dat == 0, axis=0)]
```

How do I tame it, and make it beautiful?

Comment: Are you sure that the example in the function documentation is correct? That the output corresponds to the input? I see not just removed zeros but completely different numbers. :)

Comment: Apart from that I think the code is fine. There is hardly any significantly better solution given that you are working just in 2D. Or are you aiming at general solution in any number of dimensions?

Comment: I don't need a general solution, but if I have one, all the better. As for the "completely different numbers": the function also clips the array to the interval `[0,1]`. So yes, the two correspond (or at least doctest doesn't complain).

Comment: Oh, my bad. I forgot about the clipping, I only concentrated on the cropping of zeros. You are right and your in/out example is correct. However I would suggest splitting these two functions - clip and crop should be separated - you know the rules: one function (or class) one responsibility.

Comment: Note: `np.clip( dat, 0, 1, out=dat )` makes changes to the actual parameter too. I would suggest @SCB's answer with `def crop(d, clp=True):
    dat = np.array(d)` at the beginning.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try incorporating something like this:

```
# argwhere will give you the coordinates of every non-zero point
true_points = np.argwhere(dat)
# take the smallest points and use them as the top left of your crop
top_left = true_points.min(axis=0)
# take the largest points and use them as the bottom right of your crop
bottom_right = true_points.max(axis=0)
out = dat[top_left[0]:bottom_right[0]+1,  # plus 1 because slice isn't
          top_left[1]:bottom_right[1]+1]  # inclusive
```

This could be expanded without reasonable difficulty for the general `n-d` case.

Comment: Seems like a nice solution. For large input arrays (`dat`), `true_points` might get a little large.

Comment: How large is a little large? For a 2d array, maximum size is 2 * size of array in the absolute worst case scenario. If you expect that to be more common, your original solution would probably be more effective (although maybe switch `np.all(dat[...] == 0)` to `not np.any(dat[...])`).

Comment: No loops; algorithmically efficient!

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac: Well, no loops in Python. But probably lots of loops in C... and lots of temporary allocations on top of that. And I guess also cache-unfriendly traversing of the memory... :)

Comment: @V.K.: True :-) But they are not unconstrained as first proposed by the OP, they are Numpy routines and are optimized under the hood.

Comment: I'm really just nitpicking here. Of course, I want an n-dimensional in-place solution, that also makes me coffee and paints my house, but I'm really happy with SCB's beautiful code. (For the record, I never "proposed" anything was unconstrained).

Answer (score 2):

This should work in any number of dimensions. I believe it is also quite efficient because swapping axes and slicing create only views on the array, not copies (which rules out functions such as `take()` or `compress()` which one might be tempted to use) or any temporaries. However it is not significantly 'nicer' than your own solution.

```
def crop2(dat, clp=True):
    if clp: np.clip( dat, 0, 1, out=dat )
    for i in range(dat.ndim):
        dat = np.swapaxes(dat, 0, i)  # send i-th axis to front
        while np.all( dat[0]==0 ):
            dat = dat[1:]
        while np.all( dat[-1]==0 ):
            dat = dat[:-1]
        dat = np.swapaxes(dat, 0, i)  # send i-th axis to its original position
    return dat
```

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not the prettiest approach but wanted to try something else.

```
def _fill_gap(a):
    """
    a = 1D array of `True`s and `False`s.
    Fill the gap between first and last `True` with `True`s.

    Doesn't do a copy of `a` but in this case it isn't really needed.
    """
    a[slice(*a.nonzero()[0].take([0,-1]))] = True
    return a

def crop3(d, clip=True):
    dat = np.array(d)
    if clip: np.clip(dat, 0, 1, out=dat)
    dat = np.compress(_fill_gap(dat.any(axis=0)), dat, axis=1)
    dat = np.compress(_fill_gap(dat.any(axis=1)), dat, axis=0)
    return dat
```

But it works.

```
In [639]: crop3(np.array(
     ...:   [[0,0,0,0,0,0],
     ...:    [0,0,0,0,0,0],
     ...:    [0,1,0,2,9,0],
     ...:    [0,0,0,0,0,0],
     ...:    [0,7,4,1,0,0],
     ...:    [0,0,0,0,0,0]]))
Out[639]:
array([[1, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of implementing this, which is faster for dense arrays, makes use of the `argmax` property:

```
def get_last_nz(vec):
    """Get last nonzero element position of a vector
    :param vec: the vector
    :type vec: iterable
    """
    if not isinstance(vec, np.ndarray) or vec.dtype != 'bool':
        vec = np.array(vec) > 0
    return vec.size - 1 - np.argmax(vec[::-1])

def get_first_nz(vec):
    """Get the first nonzero element position of a vector

    :param vec: the vector
    :type vec: iterable
    """
    if not isinstance(vec, np.ndarray) or vec.dtype != 'bool':
        vec = np.array(vec) > 0
    return np.argmax(vec)

def crop(array):
    y_sum = array.sum(axis=1) > 0
    x_sum = array.sum(axis=0) > 0
    x_min = get_first_nz(x_sum)
    x_max = get_last_nz(x_sum)
    y_min = get_first_nz(y_sum)
    y_max = get_last_nz(y_sum)
    return array[y_min: y_max + 1, x_min: x_max + 1]
```